# My SCSS files are no longer compiling to CSS. How do I fix this?

Tags: css, wordpress, sass, zurb-foundation

I am coding my portfolio WordPress website on top of the [Reverie Foundation WP](https://github.com/milohuang/reverie) starter theme. When editing files (html / php / scss files), I am doing so in the Reverie child theme (although the Reverie master theme folder is in the same area as my child theme).

I've used both below (separately) in order to initiate the "watch" process:

```
compass watch
```

or

```
sass --watch scss:css
```

I have an issue. When editing the _settings.scss, (for example, changing the website width):

```
$row-width: rem-calc(1000); to $row-width: rem-calc(1140);
```

My command line says:

```
Changes detected to: scss/_settings.scss
write css/app.css
write css/style.css
```

But nothing changes (in this case, making the website container wider) on the front-end of my website.

This goes for any change whatsoever that I edit or make in _settings.scss.

The weird thing is, that if I'm in style.scss and add normal css styling or add SASS variables and minxins, it works and the changes show up! But when I edit _settings.scss, nothing changes!

Does anyone have any ideas as to why this is happenning? It would be much appreciated!

EDIT - I've tried clearing and deleting the hidden sass-cache folder, but that didn't work!

I'm also running this via localhost through Xampp.

Comment: I don't see any mention of built-in compilation... Did you run a compass watch or compass compile?

Answer (score 0):

when you use compass command you should run that commands on root project . where your config.rb is there . for example your path scss is :

d:/project/demo/scss/style.scss

if your config.rb in demo folder , at the first you go to demo folder with CMD , after that run compass command . attention your css folder pass must added in config.rb

diffrent beteween Compass watch and compass compile : 
Compass watch steel working compiling your SCSS to CSS when you change SCSS files but when you enter compass compile that is compile just for ones .